# prevent ado.net from using sp_execute for security reason

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

When using ADO.NET the following statement :

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY sym_RegAna_Default DECRYPTION BY ASYMMETRIC KEY asym_RegAna_Default WITH PASSWORD = 'a very secure password :-)'
```

Is in fact send to the SQL Server as:

```
exec sp_executesql N' OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY sym_RegAna_Default DECRYPTION BY ASYMMETRIC KEY asym_RegAna_Default WITH PASSWORD = ''a very secure password :-)'' ;
```

Because it is send as a dynamic SQL string, you can see the password by using SQL Profiler.

Starting a SQL trace will produce the following output:

> exec sp_executesql N' OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY sym_RegAna_Default DECRYPTION
>   BY ASYMMETRIC KEY asym_RegAna_Default WITH PASSWORD = ''a very secure
>   password :-)'' ;

The only way that I know of fixing this is to not execute it as dynamic SQL using sp_execute but instead just use the query directly. This way, SQL Server will recognize  that it's a sensitive query and will replace the trace output with:

```
--*OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY----------------------------
```

Is is possible to force ADO.NET **NOT** to use sp_execute?

(I googled this and I can find similar questions but they always turn out to be execution plan caching issues/parameter sniffing)

For background reference, [This](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55652/how-to-restrict-sql-server-profiler-to-show-my-symmetric-key-password-while-exec/55660#55660) question was the trigger for my question.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an answer to this myself and couldn't find anything on Google, until I finally came across this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.common.serverconnection.aspx

You can use this ServerConnection object to execute a query without using sp_executesql.
This can be done using an ADO.Net SqlConnection, so you can continue to use ADO.Net after the key is open.

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection();

ServerConnection serverConnection = new ServerConnection(sqlConnection);
serverConnection.ExecuteNonQuery("OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY sym_RegAna_Default DECRYPTION BY ASYMMETRIC KEY asym_RegAna_Default WITH PASSWORD = 'a very secure password :-)'");

-- Do ADO.Net work with sqlConnection
```